# .NET6 REST API with Client Certificate Authentication always throws 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, rest, .net-6.0, ssl-client-authentication

I'm implementing rest api project using `.net6` protected with `Client Certificate Authentication`. I'm currently trying everything locally.

Following the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-your-server-to-require-certificates) I first created a selfsigned client certificate to test:

`New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "CN=TestCert,OU=UserAccounts,DC=test,DC=User,DC=com" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2","2.5.29.17={text}upn=m.peru@directio.it") -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -FriendlyName "TestCleint1" -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"`

I then exported the .pfx file to re-import it in the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` folder in `Local Computer Certificates`

This is how the authentication is configured in the API `Program.cs`:

```cs
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(
        confOpt => confOpt.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate);
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICertificateValidator, ThumprintsCertificateValidator>();

builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        if (options.Events != null)
        {
            options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
            options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;

            options.Events.OnCertificateValidated = context =>
            {
                ThumprintsCertificateValidator validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ThumprintsCertificateValidator>();
                if (validationService.ValidateCertificate(context.ClientCertificate))
                {
                    Claim[] claims = new[]
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                    };

                    context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                    context.Success();
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Principal = null;
                    context.Fail("Request certificate is not valid");
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        }
    })
    .AddCertificateCache(options =>
    {
        options.CacheSize = 1024;
        options.CacheEntryExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();


app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

//app.UseCertificateForwarding();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

and then I simply have an HomeController.cs class:

```cs
 [ApiController]
 [Route("[controller]")]
 public class HomeController : ControllerBase
 {
     private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

     public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;
     }

     [HttpGet("test")]
     [Authorize]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
     {
         return Ok("entered");
     }

     [HttpGet("test2")]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Get2()
     {
         return Ok("entered");
     }
 }
```

When I run the project, the browser asks me to choose from the available client certificates and I find my `TestCert` available for choice, and I select that one.

Then I created a Console Application to test a call to the authorization-protected endpoint
loading the `client certificate` into my `HttpClient` instance:

Console App `Program.cs`:

```cs
HttpClientHandler handler = new();

FileInfo cert = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).GetFiles("TestCert.pfx", searchOption: SearchOption.AllDirectories).First();

handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(cert.FullName, password: "{password}"));

HttpClient client = new(handler);
HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7276/Home/test");

string res = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

But the answer is always `403 forbidden`.
The first thing I noticed is that when the call is made, the `Events` property of the `CertificateAuthenticationEvents` type inside the `CertificateAuthenticationOptions` is always null so I had to add the `if (options.Events) condition != null)` because otherwise it went into exception as soon as I performed `GetAsync` from my console program, but I think that's exactly the problem.

Is something am I still missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

First of all I changed the validation service registration because I was having troubles resolving the `ThumprintsCertificateValidator` type from its `interface`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<ThumprintsCertificateValidator>();
```

Then it was enough to override the `Events` property with a new instance of `CertificateAuthenticationEvents`:

```cs
options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents() // <- NEW instance
{
    OnCertificateValidated = context =>
    {
        ThumprintsCertificateValidator validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ThumprintsCertificateValidator>();
        if (validationService.ValidateCertificate(context.ClientCertificate))
        {
            Claim[] claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
            };

            context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
            context.Success();
        }
        else
        {
            context.Principal = null;
            context.Fail("Request certificate is not valid");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

and at the time of the call the validation and assignment of the claims were successful, finally giving me access to the protected "test" endpoint.